# Invalid number error in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am executing a query in Oracle database. The column and everything is correct but I am getting an Invalid Number error for below query:

```
select COUNT(*) AS "COUNT" from NE.STRUCT B
where B.STRUCT_TYPE in ('IDC') 
and NET_ENTITY_ID is not null 
and length(NET_ENTITY_ID) = 18 
AND regexp_like(SUBSTR(NET_ENTITY_ID,15,1),'[^A-Z]') 
and TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(NET_ENTITY_ID,(length(NET_ENTITY_ID) -3), 4)) < 6000;
```

`NET_ENTITY_ID` field has only one data `ABCDEFGHXXXXNB0001`.

But not necessary that it will always be having one data. This is just for resolving the issue I am considering only this.

Error Message:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Oracle -- and any other database -- does not guarantee the order of evaluation of clauses in a `WHERE`.  You can get around this using `CASE`:

```
where B.STRUCT_TYPE in ('IDC') and
      NET_ENTITY_ID is not null and
      length(NET_ENTITY_ID) = 18 AND
      regexp_like(SUBSTR(NET_ENTITY_ID, 15, 1), '[^A-Z]') and 
      (CASE WHEN regexp_like(SUBSTR(NET_ENTITY_ID,(length(NET_ENTITY_ID) -3), 4), '^[0-9]{4}$'
            THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(NET_ENTITY_ID,(length(NET_ENTITY_ID) -3), 4)) 
       END) < 6000;
```

Comment: Yes, your solution worked but slightly slow. Can you give little bit of knowledge on how case helps?

Comment: @YogiBear . . . `case` guarantees the order of execution of its clauses.  The `THEN` clause is not executed unless the `WHEN` is true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the last 4 chars are numeric before using TO_NUMBER on them.

This will do it:

```
select COUNT(*) AS "COUNT" from 
( SELECT * FROM NE.STRUCT B
  where B.STRUCT_TYPE in ('IDC') 
  and NET_ENTITY_ID is not null 
  and length(NET_ENTITY_ID) = 18 
  AND regexp_like(SUBSTR(NET_ENTITY_ID,15,1),'[^A-Z]') 
  AND regexp_like(SUBSTR(NET_ENTITY_ID,-4),'[0-9]') 
)
where TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(NET_ENTITY_ID,-4)) < 6000;
```

NB I simplified your SUBSTR for obtaining the last 4 characters.

Comment: The last 4 characters are number but still I am getting: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.